# joining third table on eloquent pivot's extra column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

i have three tables:

**users**
    id, name

**order**
    id, date

**status**
    id, name

and defined pivot table as:

**order_user**
    order_id, status_id, user_id, created_at

so "*user_id*" is an extra column in pivot.

My **Order** model has:

```
public function statuses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Status')->withPivot('user_id')->withTimestamps(); 
    }
```

i can acces **user id** via:

```
Order::find(1)->statuses->pivot->user_id
```

but cannot figure how to get user "**name**"?

can i somehow "LEFT JOIN" user table in Order model's "statuses()" method return?

thanks!
Y

Comment: i can use `User::find(Order::find(1)->statuses->pivot->user_id)->name` on each itteration, but it seems so wrong... (i must use model 'User' in blade template...)

Comment: If it's setup properly you should be able to do `Order::find(1)->users`

Comment: @Yuray you can add belongsTo relationship at your order_user model with User model which will give you users details.

Comment: @Jeemusu, can you please write what you mean by "properly setup"? should there be another method in Order model?

Comment: @jostrohu, now i don't have order_user model... so i must create one for that pivot table?

Comment: No, you don't need an order_user model. Assuming it's a many to many relationship,  you can use belongsToMany for both your `users` and `order` models. I recommend giving this [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21) a quick watch.

Comment: i still don't get it. i itterate like: `foreach ($order->statuses as $status) { echo "statusname: ".$status->name."<br />userID:".$status->user_id;}` i would like also to have `echo "username:".$status->username`...

Answer (score 0):

this is working solution (allthough i'm sure it can be done on more elegant/eloquent way)

i updated my **Order** model as:

```
public function statuses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Status')
        ->select(array('*','users.name as username'))
        ->join('users','order_user.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

now i can:

```
foreach ($order->statuses as $status) { 
    echo "statusname: ".$status->name.
         "username:".$status->username;
    }
```

still looking for better solution, if any...

**Question**: does anyone know how to automatically reference pivot table in my JOIN clause? (instead of writing: "order_user")

br
Y